# Problems with some Japanese words

Tags: translation

A guy complimented my wig on the Internet, and then he said "またそのカツラか ぶったら、写真載せてくださいね!" I did understand that he wants me to upload more pictures of it but I can't make sense of the first sentence? And the word buttara? What is that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a line break or space in the wrong place. かぶる means "to wear [a hat]" (as in "to put on one's head").

ぶったら would be from ぶつ, meaning "to punch [so.]" and isn't relevant here.

Comment: So would you like to translate the whole sentence for me then??

Comment: Straight translation requests are off-topic here. If what I wrote doesn't answer your question, your question might not be suitable for this site. You can try Google Translate, a Japanese forum which accepts translation requests, or a basic Japanese textbook.